# Helmholtz free energy and equilibrium, examples

Tags: thermodynamics

I've read that a system for which temperature is kept constant is in thermodynamic equilibrium if Helmholtz free energy is minimized. Can someone makes me an example of a system for which temperature is kept constant that is at equilibrium and a system that is not? I'd like to apply this definition to some examples

Also I'm a bit confused about Helmoltz free energy definition:
$F=U-TS$
is $T$ the temperature of the system or the temperature of the surrounding?

Comment: A system that is connected to a work source and also to a single heat source that is at constant temperature (thermostat) the system's Helmholtz free energy is minimized at equilibrium.  Note that the temperature of the system is arbitrary during the process, what is constrained is the temperature at which heat (energy + entropy) is exchanged.

Comment: An example is a chemical reaction that is not at equilibrium occurring within the system